# How to Check if DatagrGridView has a new row c#

Tags: c#

Hi guys I was wondering how can I check if `DataGridView` has a new row when i click on Add Button. Note that, I'm using `BindingManagerBase` to bind `DataGridView` with `TextBoxes`.
I tried this code :

```
        bool Is_Empty = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1].IsNull(i))
                Is_Empty = true;
        }

        if (Is_Empty == false)
            BindingManagerBase.AddNew();
```

Comment: Maybe this can helps you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

you can use rowsAdded event. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded?view=netframework-4.8) is the example

Comment: i want check when i click on add button

Comment: You can declare a Boolean variable and set it to true on the rowsAdded event and in the click button check if the value is true or not

Comment: i tried this but with no response :

bool rowadded = false;

private void New_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if(rowadded == false)
                BindingManagerBase.AddNew();
        }

private void DataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e){
            rowadded = true;
        }

Comment: @Borkan, Did you add the event to the datagridView?

Comment: @Borkan,I mean did you bind it? something like this  this.dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(this.DataGridView1_RowsAdded);